# Azure Media Player throws exception for video format?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-media-player

I am developing with Azure Media Player 2.3.11 on Windows 10.

I have the following code:

```
// JQuery 
function initVideo(videoElementId, src, type, options, errorImageId) {
  var myPlayer = amp(videoElementId, options);
  
  myPlayer.addEventListener("error", function() {
    const err = myPlayer.error();
    const videoElement = $('#'+videoElementId);
    const errorImageElement = $('#'+errorImageId); 

    videoElement.hide();
    errorImageElement.show();
  })

  myPlayer.src([{ src: src, type: type }]);
}


const src = "video source URL (removed)"; 
const type="application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml";

var myOptions = {
      techOrder: ["azureHtml5JS", "html5FairPlayHLS", "html5"],
      nativeControlsForTouch: false,
      autoplay: false,
      controls: true,
      width: "100%",  // 622
      height: "100%", // 388
      poster: "",
      imsc1CaptionsSettings: [],
  };

initVideo("azuremediaplayer", src, type,myOptions, "errorImage");
```

The thumbnail of the video renders. If I click it promptly, the video plays fine.

If I do not click play, many HTTP 412 errors are raised, and eventually (after ~20 seconds) the error handler is called.

The final emitted error is:

```
[16:54:20.948] error: azureHtml5JS: httpDataRetriever: https://SNIPPED/644d461e-b88d-4aad-864c-36f82529248d/PH01-Test-26062023.ism/QualityLevels(128000)/Fragments(audio_und=49277328,format=mpd-time-cmaf) failed, httpStatus: 412
azuremediaplayer.min.js:19 [16:54:20.948] error: azureHtml5JS: httpDataRetriever: Module = httpDataRetriever FailureCode = 0x0020019C https://SNIPPED/644d461e-b88d-4aad-864c-36f82529248d/PH01-Test-26062023.ism/QualityLevels(128000)/Fragments(audio_und=49277328,format=mpd-time-cmaf)
azuremediaplayer.min.js:19 [16:54:22.950] error: azureHtml5JS: workflowSequencer: stepRejected: Module = httpDataRetriever FailureCode = 0x0020019C https://SNIPPED/644d461e-b88d-4aad-864c-36f82529248d/PH01-Test-26062023.ism/QualityLevels(128000)/Fragments(audio_und=49277328,format=mpd-time-cmaf)
azuremediaplayer.min.js:19 [16:54:22.950] error: azureHtml5JS: workflowCoordinator: mediaRequestRejected: audio module: httpRetryPolicy
azuremediaplayer.min.js:19 [16:54:22.950] error: azureHtml5JS: workflowCoordinator: Dispatching error: code: 0x0020019C, msg: https://SNIPPED/644d461e-b88d-4aad-864c-36f82529248d/PH01-Test-26062023.ism/QualityLevels(128000)/Fragments(audio_und=49277328,format=mpd-time-cmaf)
azuremediaplayer.min.js:19 [16:54:22.951] error: videojs: 2.3.11.2 (CODE:538968476 undefined) https://SNIPPED/PH01-Test-26062023.ism/QualityLevels(128000)/Fragments(audio_und=49277328,format=mpd-time-cmaf) [object Object]
```

Why does this happen, and how do I fix it?

There is a codepen for this on: https://codepen.io/ScottTunstall/pen/GRwNWeb